# jQuery object is changed to HTML element, why?

Tags: jquery, html, object, element

I don't understand behavior of jQuery..

I have this selector and after $ object:

```
<span class="play-btn" data-play="true">
..
   <img />
..
</span>

var currentTrack = $('span.play-btn[data-play="true"] img');
```

result:

[image -> click <-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MxJ3.png) 
(OK)

**PROBLEM**:
I need access to img object to get the attributes like `currentTrack[0].attr('src')` and others, but this code `currentTrack[0]` create HTML element, just string (`<img src="" data-id="" ..`), why??

Answer (score 0):

jQuery creates an array-like object containing the native DOM nodes, so the first native DOM node would be in `jQcollection[0]` etc.

When you log a native DOM node to the console, you get the HTML that DOM node consists of.

What you really wanted was to use the *jQuery object*, not the native DOM node

```
var currentTrack = $('span.play-btn[data-play="true"] img');

var attribute = currentTrack.attr('src');
var data-val  = currentTrack.data('id');
```

If the selector matches more than one element, and you just have to get the first one, you'd use jQuery's `eq()`

```
var currentTrack = $('span.play-btn[data-play="true"] img');

var firstTrack = currentTrack.eq(0);
```

Comment: Or possibly `eq()`, depending on the reason OP was trying to access the jQuery object by index

Comment: I tried this currentTrack.eq(0); so i got same object as the beginning: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3MxJ3.png, how is it possible (reference to itself?
)?

Comment: That's not possible, if `currentTrack` is a jQuery object, `currentTrack[0]` and `currentTrack.eq(0)` will not give you the same value, and the image you posted shows the jQuery object, which is what you wanted ?

Comment: i want get img object so from object i need access to array with index 0, but if i access like currentTrack.eq(0) or currentTrack[0] so i got same result  console.log(currentTrack.eq(0)); :D

Comment: currentTrack == currentTrack.eq(0) eqval, why (it's selector ok?) index 0, i expect img object

Comment: And why are you overwriting variables, you're sure you're not using both somehow, because getting the same object from `[0]` and `eq(0)` when working with a  jQuery object is impossible.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zw0f100y/ maybe nonsensical selector? i don't know..

Comment: Your fiddle works perfectly fine, there's only one image with `data-play="true"` so both `currentTrack` and `currentTrack.eq(0)` returns a jQuery object containing that one image?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery element is "changed to HTML" because you added `[0]`at the end of the jQuery selector.
 
This transforms a [jQuery object into a native DOM element](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/).

To select the first element, you can use:

1. `$('span.play-btn[data-play="true"] img').first()` => [.first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/)
2. `$('span.play-btn[data-play="true"] img').eq(0)` => [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)
3. `$('span.play-btn[data-play="true"] img:first')`=> [:first](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

Check [jQuery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).